# Java 8 GrouppingBy Feature

Tags: lambda, collections, java-8, java-stream

Domain 1->

```
(ContractTerms)
private BigDecimal id;
private ProgramDetails programDetails;
```

Domain2->

```
(ProgramDetails)
private BigDecimal id;
private ProcessType processTypeId;
```

I want this to be grouped by **processTypeId**, using **detachedcriteria** I'm fetching my list from DB but now I want it to be grouped by **processTypeId**

```
termValueForExtention.stream().collect(grouppingBy(ContractTerms::getProgramDetails));
```

Comment: Well, firstly, what is the type of the result? You didn't explain what went wrong?

Comment: I'm getting result in a List now from that list I need to group it in a Map where key will be the property inside object for example - ContractTerms>ProgramDetails->ProcessTypeId So I want key as processTypeId and value as List

Comment: It'll be Map<BigDecimal, List<ContractTypes>> where BigDecimal is ProcessTypeId

Comment: Using the GrouppingBy function I'm able to group it based on the properties which are inside ContractTerms but I want it to be group based on ProgramDetails which is mapped to ContractTerms

Comment: *It'll be Map<BigDecimal, List<ContractTypes>>* - `List<ContractTypes>` or `List<ContractTerms>`?

Comment: Sorry typed it wrong it'll be List<ContractTerms>

Comment: *where BigDecimal is ProcessTypeId* - in the question `processTypeId` is of type `ProcessType`, so it's actually `BigDecimal`, right?

Comment: The thing is ContractTerms is mapped with ProgramDetails, From query I'm getting List<ContractTerms> now I want to Group that list based on the property which is inside the mapped ProgramDetails

Comment: Yes, it's BigDecimal ContractTerms is mapped to ProgramDetails and ProgramDetails is mapped to ProcessType which is having Id as BigDecimal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It'll be `Map<BigDecimal, List<ContractTerms>>` where BigDecimal is
> ProcessTypeId

Then to access the property which is nested inside another property you need to replace the *method reference* in your code with the following *lambda expression*:

```
List<ContractTerms> termValueForExtention = // initializing the list of ContractTerms

Map<BigDecimal, List<ContractTerms>> result = termValueForExtention.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
        contractTerms -> contractTerms.getProgramDetails().getProcessTypeId()
    ));
```